# in-app-purchase SKProductRequest delegates not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I know the question has been asked so many times. I have looked all of it but i couldn't able to fix this issue.

I have added `Storekit framework` and created and InAppPurchaseManager class of type `NSObject`.

I am making an instance where i need to make a product request.

```
InAppPurchaseManager *inApp = [[InAppPurchaseManager alloc] init];
[inApp loadStore:@"TestProduct"];
```

I have made a class property of `SKProductsRequest`.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
```

//loadStore Method

```
- (void)loadStore:(NSString *)_productID
{
    productID = _productID;
    // restarts any purchases if they were interrupted last time the app was open
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];   
    // get the product description (defined in early sections)
    [self requestProUpgradeProductData];
}

- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData 
{

    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:productID];
    self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]     
        initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    self.productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [self.productsRequest start];
}
```

//Delegates

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:                               
      (SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    //never being called    
}

- (void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request 
{
    //never being called
}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    //never being called
}
```

My interface looks like this

```
@interface InAppPurchaseManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKRequestDelegate>
```

Please suggest how can i fix this problem.

Edit: As this

```
[self.productsRequest start];
```

executes it comes in

```
-(void) dealloc {

}
```

Comment: Do you reach `[self.productsRequest start]`?

Comment: Yes. I am continuously debugging the code. This executes [self.productsRequest start] it comes in dealloc!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This issue is fixed by making property of InAppPurchaseManager.

Comment: What does this answer mean? Its not comprehensible what it means to do

Comment: This answer does not explain what fixed the issue